How to send SMS alerts to phone numbers stored in SQLite Database in kotlin
I'm making a Crash Detection App and i want to send SMS alerts after a crash is detected. The problem I'm facing is while sending the message. I have phone numbers stored in SQLite database and want to send SMS alerts them. But when a crash is detected, logcat shows an error: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mainapp.app, PID: 13054
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress"
The format of phone numbers are correct e.g ContactName: john and ContactNumber: 03331234567 (Pakistan number) but still its throwing this error.
This is the file that is detecting crashes and generating alerts and SMS as well
package com.mainapp.app.modules.home

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.media.RingtoneManager
import android.os.Build
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.mainapp.app.ml.TfliteModel
import com.mainapp.app.modules.contacts.data.database.ContactDatabaseHelper
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer

class SensorDataProcessor(private val context: Context) {

    private val model: TfliteModel = TfliteModel.newInstance(context)
    private val contactDatabaseHelper = ContactDatabaseHelper(context)

    fun preprocessDataAndDetectCrash(sensorType: Int, sensorValues: FloatArray) {
        // Preprocess sensor data
        val preprocessedValues = preprocessData(sensorType, sensorValues)

        // Perform inference using TensorFlow Lite model
        val crashProbability = runInference(preprocessedValues)

        // Determine if a crash has occurred based on the inference result
        processInferenceResult(crashProbability)
    }

    private fun preprocessData(sensorType: Int, values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        val preprocessedValues = when (sensorType) {
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER -> preprocessAccelerometerData(values)
            Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE -> preprocessGyroscopeData(values)
            Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY -> preprocessGravityData(values)
            Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION -> preprocessOrientationData(values)
            Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR -> preprocessRotationVectorData(values)
            Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION -> preprocessLinearAccelerationData(values)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported sensor type: $sensorType")
        }
        return preprocessedValues
    }

    private fun preprocessAccelerometerData(values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        // Preprocess accelerometer data
        // Ensure that the input shape matches [1, 21]
        return values.copyOf(21)
    }

    private fun preprocessGyroscopeData(values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        // Preprocess gyroscope data
        // Ensure that the input shape matches [1, 21]
        return values.copyOf(21)
    }

    private fun preprocessGravityData(values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        // Preprocess gravity data
        // Ensure that the input shape matches [1, 21]
        return values.copyOf(21)
    }

    private fun preprocessOrientationData(values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        // Preprocess orientation data
        // Ensure that the input shape matches [1, 21]
        return values.copyOf(21)
    }

    private fun preprocessRotationVectorData(values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        // Preprocess rotation vector data
        // Ensure that the input shape matches [1, 21]
        return values.copyOf(21)
    }

    private fun preprocessLinearAccelerationData(values: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        // Preprocess linear acceleration data
        // Ensure that the input shape matches [1, 21]
        return values.copyOf(21)
    }

    private fun runInference(inputData: FloatArray): Float {
        // Create inputs for the TensorFlow Lite model
        val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, inputData.size), DataType.FLOAT32)
        inputFeature0.loadArray(inputData)

        // Run model inference
        val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)

        // Get the output feature (assuming it's a single value)
        val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

        // Extract and return the inference result
        return outputFeature0.floatArray[0] // Assuming it's a single output value
    }

    fun processInferenceResult(crashProbability: Float) {
        if (crashProbability > 4.004052544579376544) {
            triggerAlarmAndSendSMS()
        } else {
            Log.d("CrashDetection", "No crash detected. Probability: $crashProbability")
        }
    }

    private fun triggerAlarmAndSendSMS() {
        startAlarm(context)
        sendSMSAlerts()
    }

    private fun sendSMSAlerts() {
        val contacts = contactDatabaseHelper.getAllContacts()

        if (contacts.isNotEmpty()) {
            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()

            for (contact in contacts) {
                val message = "Emergency: A crash has been detected! Please check the user's location."
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact.number, null, message, null, null)
                Log.d("SMSAlert", "SMS sent to ${contact.name}")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("SMSAlert", "No contacts found in the database.")
        }
    }

    private fun triggerAlarmAndPopup() {
        // Start the alarm
        startAlarm(context)

        // Show notification with action to stop alarm
        showNotificationWithAction("Crash Detected")
    }

    private fun showNotificationWithAction(message: String) {
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notificationId = 1 // Use a unique ID for the notification
        val channelId = "CrashChannel"
        val channelName = "Crash Channel"

        // Create an intent to stop the alarm
        val stopIntent = Intent(context, StopAlertsReceiver::class.java)
        stopIntent.action = "STOP_ALERTS_ACTION"
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE) // Add FLAG_IMMUTABLE flag

        // Create a notification with action button
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Crash Detected")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, "Stop Alarm", pendingIntent) // Action button to stop alarm
            .build()

        // Create notification channel if necessary
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        // Show the notification
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
    }



    fun stopAlarm(context: Context) {
        // Stop alarm sound
        val alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
        val ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmSound)
        ringtone.stop()
    }

    private fun startAlarm(context: Context) {
        // Start alarm sound
        val alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
        val ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmSound)
        ringtone.play()
    }

    // Release resources when no longer used
    fun close() {
        contactDatabaseHelper.close()
    }
}

and this is the Database class
package com.mainapp.app.modules.contacts.data.database

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import com.mainapp.app.modules.contacts.data.model.ContactsModel

class ContactDatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // Implement database upgrade logic if needed
    }

    fun getAllContacts(): List<ContactsModel> {
        val contactList = mutableListOf<ContactsModel>()
        val db = this.readableDatabase

        val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME", null)
        cursor.use {
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val idIndex = it.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)
                val nameIndex = it.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)
                val numberIndex = it.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NUMBER)

                // Check if column index is valid before retrieving data
                val id = if (idIndex >= 0) it.getLong(idIndex) else 0
                val name = if (nameIndex >= 0) it.getString(nameIndex) else ""
                val number = if (numberIndex >= 0) it.getString(numberIndex) else ""

                val contact = ContactsModel(id, name, number)
                contactList.add(contact)
            }
        }
        return contactList
    }

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db"
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1

        const val TABLE_NAME = "contacts"
        const val COLUMN_ID = "_id"
        const val COLUMN_NAME = "name"
        const val COLUMN_NUMBER = "number"

        private const val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = """
            CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (
                $COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                $COLUMN_NAME TEXT,
                $COLUMN_NUMBER TEXT
            )
        """
    }
}


Post the exact value that was called illegal.  We need to make sure it's formatted correctly

@GabeSechan The format of phone numbers are correct e.g ContactName: john and ContactNumber: 03331234567 (Pakistan number) are being stored in database but still its throwing error
